# $http.get error in angular and node

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, get

My problem is `$http.get` instruction --> Without `$http.get` in the main page I get `"random 46"` (test ok) but if I insert `$http.get` I get `"random {{ number }}"`.

*How can I fix this?*

```
-server.js
-public
    -core.js
    -index.html
```

**server.js (node backend)**

```
//restful api
app.get('/api/random', function(req, res) {
    res.json({
        "text" : "4"
    });
});

//app
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

**core.js (angular frontend)**

```
angular.module("myModule", [])
    .controller('myController', function($scope) {
        $scope.number = 46;

        $http.get('/api/random')
            .then(function successCallback(res) {
                $scope.number = res.data;
                console.log('success');
            }, function errorCallback() {
                console.log('Error');
        });
})
```

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="myModule">

<head>
    <!-- META -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- Optimize mobile viewport -->

    <title>Random number from sa-mp</title>

    <!-- SCROLLS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"><!-- load bootstrap -->
    <style>
        html                    { overflow-y:scroll; }
        body                    { padding-top:50px; }
        #todo-list              { margin-bottom:30px; }
    </style>

    <!-- SPELLS -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- load jquery -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script><!-- load angular -->
    <script src="core.js"></script>

</head>

<!-- SET THE CONTROLLER AND GET ALL TODOS -->
<body ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="container">

        <!-- HEADER AND TODO COUNT -->
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <h1>random <span class="label label-info">{{ number }}</span></h1>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT:**
I tried

```
res.data
$scope.$apply();
```

and

```
res.data.text
$scope.$apply();
```

and

```
res.text
$scope.$apply();
```

but it didn't work.

**EDIT 2: RESOLVED**

I replaced this

```
.controller('myController', function($scope) {
```

with

```
.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
```

and used this to set data

```
$scope.number = res.data.text;
```

Comment: When placeholders do not get replaced it usually means the code is erroring out. Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: I noticed that there isn't any log ("success" or "error") on console

Answer (score 0):

Try to use $scope.$apply() at the last line of your callback.

like:

```
$http.get('/api/random')
    .then(function successCallback(res) {
        $scope.number = res.data.text;
        $scope.$apply();
        console.log('success');
    }, function errorCallback() {
        console.log('Error');
});
```

If it works. You can know more about that in this article: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Also, you should get `res.data.text` to have the right value on your html. like: `$scope.number = res.data.text`;